# In how many ways 5 couples can be seated around a circular table with some conditions attached?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways 5 couples can be seated around a circular table such that men and women sit alternatively and no person sits adjacent to his or her spouse ?

Edit: The chairs are alike! 
I have gone through few answers to the question where 5 couples are arranged in such a way that they don't sit together using inclusion and exclusion principle but I am not getting my way around when men and women also have to sit alternatively!

Comment: Are only the persons distinguishable? Or also the chairs maybe?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Start by placing the men around the table in every other chair.  Then you only have to worry about how to place the women.  Inclusion-exclusion should work for that, as each woman has two forbidden positions out of the five possible positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $4!$ ways to place the men in such a way that men and women will sit alternatively.

Place them and label the spots where the men have taken their seats clockwise with $a,b,c,d,e$.

Now we will take a look at the possible configurations for women.

Without further conditions there are $5!$ configurations for women.

Let $A$ denote the set of these configurations where the man that sits
at $a$ has his wife next to him.

This similar for $B,C,D,E$ where the capitals correspond with labels
$b,c,d,e$ respectively.

The answer to the question is then $4!\left|A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}\cap C^{\complement}\cap D^{\complement}\cap E^{\complement}\right|=4!\left(5!-\left|A\cup B\cup C\cup D\cup E\right|\right)$
so it remains to find $\left|A\cup B\cup C\cup D\cup E\right|$.

This can be done by means of inclusion/exclusion. Up to a certain
level we can also make use of symmetry (e.g. notice that of course
$\left|A\cap B\right|=\left|B\cap C\right|$) but here we must be
careful.

At first hand we find that: $$\left|A\cup B\cup C\cup D\cup E\right|=5\left|A\right|-5\left|A\cap B\right|-5\left|A\cap C\right|+5\left|A\cap B\cap C\right|+5\left|A\cap B\cap D\right|-5\left|A\cap B\cap C\cap D\right|+\left|A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap E\right|$$

Then checking the cases one by one we find:

- $\left|A\right|=2\times4!=48$
- $\left|A\cap B\right|=3\times3!=18$
- $\left|A\cap C\right|=4\times3!=24$
- $\left|A\cap B\cap C\right|=4\times2!=8$
- $\left|A\cap B\cap D\right|=6\times2!=12$
- $\left|A\cap B\cap C\cap D\right|=5\times1!=5$
- $\left|A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap E\right|=2\times0!=2$

So our final answer is: $$4!\left(5!-5\times48+5\times18+5\times24-5\times8-5\times12+5\times5-26\right)=24\times13=312$$

---

I hope that I did not make any mistakes. Check me on it.

Comment: Thank you ! That was quite helpful. :D

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: I finally got around to checking your answer this morning.  While searching for the problem, I found an incorrect answer on the website [Quora](https://www.quora.com/In-how-many-ways-can-5-couples-be-seated-around-a-circular-table-such-that-no-husband-sits-next-to-his-wife).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for checking. I gave the same answer on Quora now.

Comment: While I am not a member of Quora, it was nice of you to provide a correct solution there.  My suspicion is that Quora users would be better off using this site to have their mathematical questions addressed.

Comment: The question on Quora is different because it lifts the condition on alternating seating. This here is the well known Ménage problem whereas the one on Quora is just a straightforward application of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @N.Shales Thank you for spotting this. I deleted my answer on Quora.

Comment: @drhab: Sorry to be a pain. Hope it wasn't too much of an inconvenience. If you're anything like me, though, you don't like being wrong publicly. :) I (+1)ed your answer here, it's actually the more interesting variation anyway. Good work!

Comment: @N.Shales You enabled me to withdraw a mispublication within short time and I am very grateful for that! Also thank you for upvote and compliment. I owe a lot to persons like you and also N.F. Taussig. The things that went wrong are my own fault ( of no one else!): just too lazy to read the question properly. Dozens of times I rebuked myself in this but...Well again: let me do that better from now on :-).

Answer (score 1):

There are $P(5)=(5-1)!=4!$ [circular permuations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html) of the $5$ men.

Now consider the arrangement: $*M_1*M_2*M_3*M_4*M_5$.

There are $3$ arrangements of $W_1$:
$$1) *M_1*M_2\color{red}{W_1}M_3*M_4*M_5\\
2) *M_1*M_2*M_3\color{red}{W_1}M_4*M_5\\
3) *M_1*M_2*M_3*M_4\color{red}{W_1}M_5\\$$
There are $3,2$ and $2$ arrangements of $W_2$, respectively:
$$\begin{align} 1) \ \ \ \ \ &I) \color{blue}{W_2}M_1*M_2\color{red}{W_1}M_3*M_4*M_5\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ &II) *M_1*M_2\color{red}{W_1}M_3\color{blue}{W_2}M_4*M_5\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ &III)*M_1*M_2\color{red}{W_1}M_3*M_4\color{blue}{W_2}M_5\\
2) \ \ \ \ \ &I)\color{blue}{W_2}M_1*M_2*M_3\color{red}{W_1}M_4*M_5\\
&II)*M_1*M_2*M_3\color{red}{W_1}M_4\color{blue}{W_2}M_5\\
3) \ \ \ \ \ &I)\color{blue}{W_2}M_1*M_2*M_3*M_4\color{red}{W_1}M_5\\
&II)*M_1*M_2*M_3\color{blue}{W_2}M_4\color{red}{W_1}M_5\\
\end{align}$$
There are $1,3,2,1,2,1,3$ arrangements of the rest women, respectively (verification is left as an exercise).

Due to symmetry, the final number of arrangements of the $5$ pairs is $4!\cdot 13=312$.